# Логика в построении текста

Tags: оформление-текста, абзац

Как не ошибиться в членении текста на абзацы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Функции абзаца](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook029/01/part-010.htm#i582) Прочитайте. Если что будет непонятно, обращайтесь, объясним.